# How to pass data from cordova plugin to index.html in Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am creating cordova application witch are showing call logs, so i make plugin and i get calls log in native java code and i don`t know how to pass it back to index.html.

this is my plugin javascript

```
 navigator.callslog= {};
 navigator.callslog.show = function () { cordova.exec (null, null, "callslog", "show", []);};
```

And this is java code for my plugin

```
 @Override
 public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)
 {

        if (action.equals("show")) {
            // get call logs

            String calls = getCallDetails(callbackContext);
            callbackContext.success();
            Log.v("Calls", calls);

            this.webView.postMessage("callsLog", "show");
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
 }
```

And in index.js i call plugin and data was printed in logcat it works but i don`t know how to get the data and represent in index.html

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    console.log('Recevedod event ');

    var callsLog= navigator.splashscreen.show();
}
```

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this first parameter is success call back and second one is fail callback.
instead of null and null

you have to do like this

```
navigator.callslog.show = function () { cordova.exec (successcb, failcb, "callslog", "show", []);};

function successcb(s){
console.log(s);//what you passed from Java code
}

function failcb(e){
console.log("Err cb");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass string as an argument for callbackContext.success() method as

**callbackContext.success(calls);**

Comment: Thank you but in java script how can i get it?